# Perl Setting Value of Constant to value of Hash Key

Tags: perl, hashmap, constants

Is there any way to set the value of a Perl Constant to a value in a Perl Hash?

This is not working:

```
use constant TEST => $configData{'key'};
print TEST."\n";
```

This prints just the newline character.

Is this a misuse of the concept of a Constant? The values are still known at compile time, they just do not live inside a perl module or the perl script itself.

Comment: Where and when are you defining the hash and assigning the values?  Personally, I wouldn't define a constant.  I would use the [Readonly](http://search.cpan.org/~sanko/Readonly-2.00/lib/Readonly.pm) module.

Comment: @RonBergin I am using an external subroutine to load the key/value pairs into a hash and return it to the calling script.

`my %configData = loadConfigHash('config.dat')`

The keys and values in the hash are loaded correctly, I can print them out directly after this call.

Comment: Defining the constant occurs at compile time but declaring the lexical var (hash) occurs at runtime which is why the constant doesn't hold the value you expect.

Comment: Not a detailed answer but this works when you wrap assigning $configData{key} in a BEGIN block, so it seems it's not in fact known at compile time. `my %configData; BEGIN { $configData{key} = "foo"; } use constant TEST => $configData{key}; print TEST . "\n";` works.

Comment: [This article](http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html) may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks guys. Great answers. It seems I have some learning to do about the module initialization process.

Comment: I don't use the constant pragma because the constants don't interpolate in double quoted strings.

Comment: @swornabsent I was able to recreate your example. However, assigning the value of the Hash itself inside the BEGIN block does not work. I.e. `my %configData; BEGIN { %configData = loadConfigHash('config.dat'); } use constant TEST => $configData{'key'}; print TEST."\n";` Prints only the newline.

Comment: You're invoking subroutine `loadConfigHash` in the BEGIN block. Are you using `strict` and `warnings`?

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is - `constant` is for ... constant values, not variables. Assigning a variable to a constant doesn't make a great deal of sense.

If you want to set it to a variable value, then... well, the real answer is don't use "constants" in the first place for that. It's a place for setting hardcoded parameters in your script, rather than for things you need to evaluate later.

What it looks like you're doing is having a 'static-ish' config that you load once and use repeatedly. Can I suggest instead you might consider an object?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyConfig;

sub new {
   my ( $class ) = @_; 
   my $self = {}; 

   #do some stuff to read 'config' from your file into `$self`. 
   $self->{'key'} = "some value here";
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self; 
}

sub get_test { 
   my ( $self ) =  @_;
   return $self -> {'key'}
}

package main;

my $config = MyConfig -> new();
print $config -> get_test;
```

In this way - by declaring an object - you're making clear that people shouldn't be 'meddling' with it. (they technically can, but anyone who does needs poking).

And because you have a method (subroutine built into the object) called 'get_test' - but nothing that lets you *change* the object - then ... you achieve a very similar result.

This approach also works very nicely for 'loading external data' - because anyone *using* your external data can import it from *your* module, without having to worry about the stuff hidden inside.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example using the Readonly module.  I put the sub directly in the test script, but it could be external.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Readonly;
use Data::Dumper;

Readonly::Hash my %configData => loadConfigHash();

sub loadConfigHash {
    my %hash = (one => 1,
                two => 2,
                three => 3);
    return %hash;
}

print Dumper \%configData;

# this assignment will fail and generate a fatal error
$configData{two} = 4;
print Dumper \%configData;
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. I've downloaded the Readonly module and will be using it instead of constant

Comment: You should consider [Neil Bowers' excellent review](http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html) first.

Answer (score 1):

`use constant` happens at compile time regardless of where it appears in your source code.

It works analogously to encapsulating the provided value in a subroutine with an empty prototype.

I have a feeling you are not using [strict](https://metacpan.org/pod/strict) and `$configData{'key'};` does not exist at the time your `use constant` statement is executed.

I would actually recommend using [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) which provides interpolatable fast constants of all kinds.

However, you can solve your problem by either wrapping the definition of `$configData{'key'};` and `use constant` in the same `BEGIN` block as in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %configData;

BEGIN {
    $configData{'key'} = 'value';
}

use constant TEST => $configData{'key'};

print TEST, "\n";
```

If you try to do this at run time, you'll have to predeclare `TEST` with an empty prototype.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub TEST();

my %configData;

$configData{'key'} = 'value';

require constant;
constant->import(TEST => $configData{'key'});

print TEST, "\n";
```

Better to use `Const::Fast`.